# Ignore all files other than specific type of file, for directory comparison in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare two directories for all ".bin" files in them. There can be some other extension type files such as ".txt", ".tar.bz2" in those directories. I want to get the common files as well as files which are not common.
I tried using filecmp.dircmp(), but I am not able to use the ignore parameter with some wild card to ignore those files. Is there any solution which I can use to serve my purpose.

Comment: by common files you mean those .bin files that are identical between the two directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the common subset of *.bin files in the two folders and remove the first part of the path (the folder name), then pass them to `cmpfiles()`:

```py
import filecmp
from pathlib import Path

dir1_files = [f.relative_to('folder1') for f in Path('folder1').glob('*.bin')]
dir2_files = [f.relative_to('folder2') for f in Path('folder2').glob('*.bin')]
common_files = set(dir1_files).intersection(dir2_files)

match, mismatch, error = filecmp.cmpfiles('folder1', 'folder2', common_files)
```

If you want to avoid the preselection of common files, you can instead take the union of the two sets:

```py
common_files = set(dir1_files).union(dir2_files)
```